# Fail to initiate connection in Signal R in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

Below is my .aspx page code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="chat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var query = window.location.search;
            var toRemove = '?id=';
            var gorge = query.replace(toRemove, '');
            // Proxy created on the fly
            var hub = $.connection.chatHub;
            $.connection.hub.qs = "Id=" + gorge;
            // Start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start(function () {
                //chat.server.getAllOnlineStatus();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container" class="wrap">
        <div id="chatbox" class="chatbox">
            <ul id="frndcontact">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my Hub class

```
[HubName("chatHub2")]

public class Chat2 : Hub
{
    private SqlConnection objconn;
    string Connstr = @"Data Source=somevalue;Initial Catalog=somevalue;Integrated Security=True;";
    public Task JoinGroup()
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "foo");
    }
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string strQuery)
    {
        SqlCommand objcmd;
        SqlDataAdapter objda;
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            objconn = new SqlConnection(Connstr);
            objconn.Open();
            objcmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, objconn);
            objda = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);

            objda.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
        finally
        {
            objconn.Close();
            objcmd = null;
            objda = null;
        }
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Context.QueryString["id"]);
        string sql = string.Format("exec getfriend '" + id + "' ");
        System.Data.DataTable dtgetfriend = GetDataTable(sql);      
    }}
```

Now when I am debugging I am not able to get my breakpoint hit on `OnConnected`. Why am I not able to start with this piece of code?

Also I have added this code in global.asax

```
 public void Application_Start()
 {
     RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not subscribed to the hub.  Prior to start you need to declare at least one client side function and you need to reference your hub by the correct name.  So if you modify your JS to be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var query = window.location.search;
        var toRemove = '?id=';
        var gorge = query.replace(toRemove, '');
        // Proxy created on the fly
        var hub = $.connection.chatHub2;
        $.connection.hub.qs = "Id=" + gorge;

        hub.client.foo = function() {};
        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            //chat.server.getAllOnlineStatus();
        });
    });
```

You'll be in good shape.

Comment: This worked liked a charm but i am confused why we have write this line hub.client.foo = function() {};...If i remove this line then i am not able to call Override Task OnConnected method ....y so?

Comment: In order to know what hubs a client is subscribed to SignalR looks for bound client side methods associated with the hub.  There can be many hubs per application but you wouldn't want to trigger OnConnected on every hub if you're not using all of them right?